# Override Oscar models using other Oscar models from the same app

Tags: django, django-models, python-import, django-oscar

I need achieve something like this:

```
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct
from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import ProductClass

Product(AbstractProduct):
     @property
     display(self):
          if self.product_class = ProductClass.objects.get(pk=1):
               #do something
          else:
               #do something else
```

But when I do a `from catalogue.models import Product` elsewhere I invariably get the default Oscar `Product` and not my overridden `Product` with the `display()` property.
I believe this is because the built-in Oscar `Product` is being registered before my custom one when I do the `import ProductClass`.

However to achieve the functionality I need it's vital I have access to `ProductClass` in the forked version of `Product`!

How can I get around this catch-22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When overriding Oscar models you need to move any non-abstract imports below the class definitions that are meant to replace models that come with Oscar. Here's [an example](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto/how_to_customise_models.html#example).

In your case it should be safe to just move the `models` import below:

```
from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct


Product(AbstractProduct):
    @property
    display(self):
        if self.product_class == ProductClass.objects.get(pk=1):
            #do something
        else:
            #do something else


from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```

The `display` property will continue to work since by the time it is called for the first time, the module scope will already contain all the necessary models.

I've changed the import to `*` to make sure that all other models are loaded from Oscar.

Please note that the star import will inevitably try to import the `Product` model as well but Oscar will notice that a model by that name is already registered and will simply discard the other definition. It is ugly and confusing but that's the Oscar's recommended method.

Comment: Thanks Patrys. What if the use of ProductClass was not inside the display() method but instead used e.g to define a class variable, and therefore needed when the Product class is first loaded - what would you do then?

Comment: I don't see how you can work around that without overriding `ProductClass` with your own but in practice I've not hit that problem often (for example `ForeignKey` fields allow you to pass a string instead of a reference).